# How to replace text with html

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a phone number with a new phone number.
However, it's not working with the `<p>` tags right now.

I can replace it with a word and it changes it.  But when I use HTML it doesn't work

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#navbarPhoneNumber").html("<p id='phonenumber'></p>");
});
</script>
```

Comment: How is it not working? What's your expected result? What's the actual result?

Comment: Attach your html file in the post

Comment: Here it is... https://jsfiddle.net/h1y50kgq/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jquery for this simple example, just use DOM's simple API function `.getElementById`.

```
document.getElementById('navbarPhoneNumber').innerText = <new phone number>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML after you get your element to replace your text

```
  
  document.getElementById("navphonenumber").innerHTML = phonenumber;
```

Here is a solution I wrote